# C++ substring seems to be pointing at wrong spot

Tags: c++, string, substr

I am reading a text file with C++.
Since I am new to C++, I added a bunch of "cout" statements to see how things behave.
I got an output for which I found no explanation, and hopefully someone here can point me to some relevant text.

1. I read a line
2. Print the line
3. Print the first 2 characters in "line" with "substr()"
4. Copy the line into a work area ("mybuffer")
5. Print a substring of my work area, 10 characters long

The problem: 
(a) The output from (3) seems to be an escape sequence (unprintable characters). If I change the length of the substring from 2 to 4, I get a single /.
(b) Even though the content of "mybuffer" looks right (the first two characters are indeed //), the substring function is returning only seven (printable) characters.

```
while( std::getline( file, line ) )
{
foundeq = 0;
clearthis = 0;
mybuffer = line;
cout<< "line>>" << line<<"\n";
cout<<"first 2 chars in line>>"<<line.substr(0,2)<<"\n";
cout<< "mybuffer>>" << mybuffer<<"\n";
cout<<"first 10 chars in mybuffer>>"<<mybuffer.substr(0,10)<<"\n";
```

Output:

```
    line>>//--------------------------------------------------
    first 2 chars in line>>\357\273
    mybuffer>>//--------------------------------------------------
    first 10 chars in mybuffer>>//-----
```

What is going on??

Thanks in advance for your comments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Short Answer

Your file is encoded in [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) and it has a [Byte Order Mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-8) at the beginning.

#### Slightly longer answer

So your console is printing the first two numbers in octal for you. 0357 and 0273. The third character of the [UTF-8 BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-8) is 0277. Presumably when you console sees these three characters in a row, it decides to not print them.

Also, presumably the 4th character in your file is a `/` that fits in one byte.

Comment: I had guessed that much, thanks for the clarification. A question remains: why are those characters included in the substring?
(PS I am not allowed to up-vote yet, otherwise I would.)

Comment: They are the first three bytes of the file. `std::string` doesn't really understand strings per say, it's just a series of bytes.

Comment: It is common for tools to hide weird (read non-ascii) characters. So depending on the editor you are using, you are not seeing the first 3 characters even though they are there. `\357 \273 \277` are the octal representations of `0xEF 0xBB 0xBF` which are truly the first 3 characters in your file, even if you can't see them.

Comment: @Kyle: More likely, nandomtl's editor understand's UFT-8 BOMs, parsed those characters as a BOM, and then parsed the rest of the file as UTF-8.

Comment: @Bill I get it. Those characters are **within** the file (thanks for the BOM link - I did see ï»¿ in a text file recently). The only thing somewhat out of the ordinary is that the console is disregarding those characters when (and only when) printable characters are in the stream. Thank you, Bill! And Happy 2015!

Comment: I did not mention before, but I am running under OS X. The BOM characters show with Text Edit, but they do not show with Open Office or Text Wrangler. I am now adding some code to skip BOM characters in case they are present.